# I have this error when testing a form in laravel 6

Tags: php-7, laravel-6

""Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: userBooks.show] [URI: userBooks/{userBook}].""
I am working with Infyom templates

Comment: maybe, you will show controller method and your routes?

Comment: public function store(CreateUserBookRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $userBook = $this->userBookRepository->create($input);

        Flash::success('User Book saved successfully.');

        return redirect(route('userBooks.show' , ['id'=> $userBook->id]));
    }

Comment: ['userBook'=> $userBook->id] or without param name return redirect(route('userBooks.show' , [$userBook->id]));  ?

Comment: I tried without param name and it gives me this error InvalidArgumentException
View [userBooks.show] not found.

Comment: can you try dd($userBook->id) in controller? What php artisan route:list command return?

Comment: it's too long I will post it in two comments

Comment: |        | POST      | register                            |
    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | w
eb,guest                    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                            | register
    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | w
eb,guest                    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | userBooks                           | userBooks.index
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@index                          | w

Comment: eb                          |
|        | POST      | userBooks                           | userBooks.store
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@store                          | w
eb                          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | userBooks/create                    | userBooks.create
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@create                         | w
eb                          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | userBooks/{userBook}                | userBooks.show
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@show                           | w
eb                        |

Comment: |        | DELETE    | userBooks/{userBook}                | userBooks.destroy
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@destroy                        | w
eb                          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | userBooks/{userBook}                | userBooks.update
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@update                         | w
eb                          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | userBooks/{userBook}/edit           | userBooks.edit
    | App\Http\Controllers\UserBookController@edit                           | w